# Convert time into local time zone

Tags: android, timezone

I am trying to convert the time receive into local time zone in android.
I am hitting API on server and server is on another timezone, so time received from server is according to that TimeZone Suppose UK.
But android phone is in India, So I want to convert the time received into local time.

**Suppose I received.**
**From Server:** 2016-03-25 08:03:28.724304

**Actual Time to be shown in android:** 2016-03-25 13:43:28.724304

How can we convert it into local time.

Comment: As I recall there is one very specific C API call for this (don't have the code open at the moment), the others would fail. I thought the Android Java API had it sown up nicely but that of course wouldn't apply on the server.

Comment: Are you certain the server isn't just going to give you UTC, always? If it's giving the server-local time, that's appalling...

Answer (score 1):

You have got a Date and need to format it using the correct Timezone.

```
Calendar currentdate = Calendar.getInstance();
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
TimeZone obj = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UK");
formatter.setTimeZone(obj);
System.out.println("Local:: " +currentdate.getTime());
System.out.println("UK:: "+ formatter.format(currentdate.getTime())
```

I hope you will get what you are expecting. :)

Answer (score 0):

Never use time from API for your case
use Calender.class
there are variety of format available you can choose from them
**Time at server cannot be converted to your locale.
To convert you might need to give locale for the time in server and locale for the time in your app**